# Hiding main activity when widget is tapped

Tags: android, button, android-widget

I have developed an app widget for android which when tapped, an activity with a Dialog Theme appears. However if from the main activity the home button is pressed and then try to tap the widget again, the main activity appears on the background. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? i.e main activity not to appear when widget is tapped anifest

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".myWidget" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
           android:resource="@xml/res_widget" />
</receiver>
```

AppWidgetProvider.java

```
public void onUpdate(Context c, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
     for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    Intent fireDialog = new Intent(c,Execute.class);
    fireDialog.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // if i click home when i am in main activity i still get it on background-this doesnt help neither though
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, fireDialog, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.myButton, pendingIntent);
    Log.w(LOG_TAG,"Called");
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
     }
}

public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
{
 final String action=intent.getAction();
 if(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)){
     final int appWidgetId=intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
     if(appWidgetId!=AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID){
         this.onDeleted(c,new int[]{appWidgetId});
     }
 }else{
     super.onReceive(c, intent);
 }
```

Comment: can you post your relevant code, including your manifest?

Comment: What do you mean with "the main activity appears on the background"

Comment: The main Activity is probably an activity in the same package of the app widget. To solve this, a primitive solution would be to add to the MainActiivty .. in the `onPause()` function: `finish();`

Comment: @Dominic I mean that when I press the back button to exit the widget or in general finish dealing with the widget, I can see the main activity activity running.